# Extract grouped numbers and their position in a string

Tags: vb.net

Looking for a way to loop through a string, searching for grouped numbers, storing their position in string, their lenght and value.

For example:

```
Private s as String = "Tes12tin5g_44_for156another4624."

Private numbers As New List(Of GroupedNumbers)

GroupNumbers(s)
```

The variable numbers should content a list with the next items:

```
Value 12, Position 3, Length 2
Value 5, Position 8, Lenght 1
Value 44, Position 11, Length 2
Value 156, Position 16, Lenght 3
Value 4624, Position 24, Lenght 4
```

Assuming position start in 0.

I only can detect numbers but don't know how to detect them in groups.

```
Private Sub GroupNumbers(ByVal s As String)
    Dim pos As Integer = 0
    For Each c As Char In sTextoOrígen
        If IsNumeric(c) Then
            numbers.Add(New GroupedNumbers(AscW(c), pos, 1))
        End If
        pos += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i'll try what i can do.. hold on

Comment: `Value 5, Position 18, Length 1` should also be found, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex:

```
 Dim s As String = "Tes12tin5g_44_for156another4624."
 Dim r As New Regex("\d+")

        For Each m As Match In r.Matches(s)
            Debug.Print(String.Format("Value {0}, Position {1}, Length {2}",
                                          m.Value, m.Index, m.Length))
        Next
```

You need: `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`

this give me:

```
Value 12, Position 3, Length 2
Value 5, Position 8, Length 1
Value 44, Position 11, Length 2
Value 156, Position 17, Length 3
Value 4624, Position 27, Length 4
```

Comment: This is working very good. Is it the most optimized way to do that? A loop  through the string searching and grouping is even possible?

Comment: I don't know if it is the most optimized way, but I think it is a lot better than using a loop.